# Cannot create elasticsearch mapping or get date field to work

Tags: elasticsearch, scrapy, kibana, elastic-stack

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true."
      }
  "status" : 400
```

I've read that the above is because type are deprecated in elasticsearch 7.7, is that valid for data type? I mean how am I suppose to say I want the data to be considered as a date?
My current mapping has this element:

```
"Time": {
  "type": "text",
  "fields": {
    "keyword": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "ignore_above": 256
    }
  }
},
```

I just wanted to create it again with type:"date", but I noticed even copy pasting the current mapping (which works) yields an error... The index and mappins I have are generate automatically by https://github.com/jayzeng/scrapy-elasticsearch
My goal is simply to have a date field, I have all my date in my index, but when I want to filter in kibana I can see it is not considered as a date field. And modyfing mapping doesn't seem like an option.
Obvious ELK noob here, please bare with me (:

[image]

The error is quite ironic because I pasted the mapping from an existing index/mapping...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing this because of the breaking [change in 7.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#include-type-name-defaults-false) regarding named doc types.

Long story short, instead of

```
PUT example_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc_type": {
      "properties": {
        "Time": {
          "type": "date",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you should do

```
PUT example_index
{
  "mappings": {        <-- Note no top-level doc type definition
    "properties": {
      "Time": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not familiar with your scrapy package but at a glance it looks like it's just a wrapper around the native py ES client which should forward your mapping definitions to ES.

---

Caveat: if you have your fields defined as `text` and you intend to change it to `date` (or add a `field` of type `date`), you'll get the following error:

```
mapper [Time] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [date]
```

You basically have two options:

1. drop the index, set the new mapping & reindex everything (easiest but introduces downtime)
2. extend the mapping with a new field, let's call it `Time_as_datetime` and update your existing docs using a [`script`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) (introduces a brand new field/property -- that's somewhat verbose)

Comment: I actually have no top level, see the picture I added in the original post.
I can drop the index it's not a problem. But unfortunately that package I'm using doesn't let me define mapping, so I guess I'd have to do it myself and then it wouldn't overwrite it (hopefully)

Comment: What you shared is just a snippet of the mapping. Can you share the top level too? Second, if the package does not support adding a mapping, you can do so using the python client or Kibana.

Comment: The screenshots I shared are from Kibana. And what do you mean? There is no top level, the screenshot is from the top, the rest are just other elements with different names

Comment: Can you paste the result of `GET your_index_name` from Kibana?

Comment: I figured what was wrong for the mapping to work. Basically if I remove the "item" root object it goes through and my mapping is created. Problem is, with my scrapy module doesn't work after this because it uses ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE = 'items'.
So I can have maping:{properties:{....}} but not maping:{properties:{items:{....}}}, any idea why?

Comment: That's what I was saying. It's an ES version thing... The package probably wasn't properly updated. Try setting the mapping in Kibana -- you don't need to set it every time when you scrape something and send it to ES... It can be set once and then when you sync the docs, you send the payload w/o the object type -- just a plain dict. Hope it makes sense.